# How to paginate results in vb.net without datagrid? (One by one)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Im using ms-access (OleDb) and vb.net.

[image]

I have a window where I want to print records one by one...

I have buttons for go to first product, go to previous product, go to next product and go to last product. As you see I'm not using a datagrid. Well the problem begins with the following:

I had planned to use the same paginate system from my PHP website, But something happens.. the program displayed "Error in clause from". Surfing the web, I found the surprise that I cant use it, because the LIMIT clause is specifically for SQL!

¿ Is there any other similar clause like limit ? I read that in vb.net people use TOP, but i cant figure out how to establish a limit of records with TOP.

Could you give me ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take off the limit and save the datatable or dataset as public variable inside the form class. I will also make sure to include a ORDER BY columnname to make sure records are shown in proper order

then you can use (in case of a datatable, in case of dataset use dataset.tables(0))

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FirstValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("ColumnName").ToString

    LastValue = dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1).Item("ColumnName").ToString


    CurrentItem += 1
    NextItem = dt.Rows(CurrentItem).Item("ColumnName").ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u dude, you give me the solution with your idea!